# Printing Comment pages only with Acrobat

Tags: pdf

How to print only the comment pages only in acrobat professional 7?

I have found a suggestion in one of the web pages
to use javascript to extract the comment pages only, 
but I am unable to complete the script.

```
- Use a JavaScript to scan the PDF "this.syncAnnotScan"
- Then make a variable (i.e. "a" ) equal to zero and then increment it one for every page in the doent.
- Make another variable (i.e. "b") equal to "this.getAnnots" using the first variable ( "a" ) as the "nPage:" value.
- Set an "IF" statement checking if the second value ( "b") is not NULL then use "this.print" using the first variable ( "a") as both the "nStart:" and "nEnd" parameters.
- Make sure that you have the preference set to print comments in the Acrobat Preferences.
```

I have tried but unable to complete the script.

Kindly help me.

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for a solution of the same problem (printing only PDF pages with annotations) and I'm sharing the script here so others may benefit.

Simply save the following as **printAnnotatedPages.js** and put it into the **Javascript** subfolder of the Adobe Acrobat installation:

```js
// Print only pages with annotations in them
function printAnnotatedPages() {

    // Sync document annotations
    this.syncAnnotScan();

    // Check if printRange is available (Acrobat 11 or newer)
    var pagesRange = null;
    if (typeof app.formsVersion != "undefined" && app.formsVersion >= 11.0)
    {
        // Enable printRange
        pagesRange = [];
    }

    // Scan pages for annotations
    var startPage = -1;
    var new_set = false;
    for (var page = 0; page < this.numPages; page++)
    {
        // Check whether the current page has annotations
        var hasComments = this.getAnnots({nPage: page});
        if (hasComments != null) {
            // This page has annotations
            // Check whether this is a new set
            if (!new_set) {
                // Start new set of pages
                startPage = page;
                new_set = true
            }
        } else {
            // This page hasn't annotations
            // Print the set of pages (if any)
            if (new_set) {
                new_set = false;
                if (pagesRange != null) {
                    // Add set of pages to print list
                    pagesRange.push([startPage, (page-1)]);
                } else {
                    // Print this set (displays Print UI)
                    this.print({nStart: startPage, nEnd: (page-1)});
                }
            }
        }
    };

    // Final check
    if (pagesRange != null) {
        // Print the last set of pages (if any)
        if (new_set) {
            // Add the last set of pages to print list
            new_set = false;
            pagesRange.push([startPage, (page-1)]);
        }

        // Print using the range function
        if (pagesRange.length > 0) {
            var pp = this.getPrintParams();
            pp.interactive = pp.constants.interactionLevel.full;
            pp.printRange=pagesRange;
            this.print(pp); 
        } else {
            // No pages with annotations
            app.alert({nIcon: 1, cTitle: "Print annotated pages",
                cMsg: "There are no annotated pages in this document."});
        }   
    } else {
        // Print the last set (displays Print UI)
        if (new_set) {
            new_set = false;
            this.print({nStart: startPage, nEnd: (page-1)});
        }
    }
}

// Add menu item to the File menu
app.addMenuItem({ cName:"PrintAnnotatedPages", cUser:"Print pages with annotations...", cParent:"File",
          cExec:"printAnnotatedPages();", cEnable: "event.rc = (event.target != null);", nPos: 16 });
```

This adds a new menu **Print pages with annotations...** under **File** in Acrobat when there is a document opened; I've tested it and works with v9 and DC successfully. With versions before 11 - due to missing API - you must confirm the print dialog before each group of pages, though.

Answer (score 0):

with Acrobat Reader XI, this creates the list with extra spaces, which subsequently does not print properly. That is, for the following:
9 , 17 - 21 , 23 , 25 - 26 , 29 - 30 , 33 - 36 , 40 - 41 , 45 - 47 , 49 , 52 - 54 , 56 - 59 , 64 - 68 , 70 - 73 , 76 - 78 , 83 - 90 , 92 - 93 , 95 - 96 , 99 , 104 , 107 - 108 , 113 , 117 - 120 , 123 - 124 , 163 - 165 , 194 - 196 , 223 - 224 , 226 , 230 , 233 , 237 , 239 - 240

Only the first page prints.

If I manually remove the extra spaces:
9, 17-21,

It works fine. Is it possible to adjust the script to remove the spaces? I think the ones directly after the comma are fine.